# error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project image processing and i get an error when run this code.
I use python and opencv in the project.The error was,

```
error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

and this is the code i used,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y),(x+w, y+h),(255,0,0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        k = cv2.waitkey(30) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please help i was stucked here for 5 hrs.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your ret value True or False?

Answer (score 0):

The `img` variable does not contain the correct dimensions. If you have only one camera in your system use `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` instead of `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`.

Comment: So what should i use instead of 'img'?can you please give the code which i should use?And i have disabled my internal webcam.So i also think it should be cv2.VideoCapture(0).Thanks.

Comment: I just wanted to say that img variable was getting a none type object because cv2.VideoCapture was not working. That error was occurred at that line because img variable was pointing to a none type object.

Comment: Is the code still giving same error after changing cv2.VideoCapture?

Comment: I think the problem was in cam.After changing that cv2.VideoCapture(1) to cv2.VideoCapture(0) it worked.Thanks..